# Making a Kendo Grid link template behave like a command

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid, and instead of having a custom command:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: data,
    columns:
    [
        ...
        { command: { text: "Details", click: showDetails }, title: " " }
    ]
});
```

I'd like the same behavior to occur but on a standard link. Is it possible?

This is the functionality I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/ERgkA/2/

But want it to behave like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/qXAf6/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to what I use in my own projects. You can use whatever markup you desire and style it however you want to make it look functional.

```
function showDetails(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = dataItem.quantity;
}

var data = [
    { name: "name1", quantity: 1 },
    { name: "name2", quantity: 4 },
    { name: "name3", quantity: 9 }
];

var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: data,
    columns: [
        { field: 'name', template: '<a href="\\#" class="k-button link">#= name #</a>' },
        { field: 'quantity' }
    ]
}).data('kendoGrid');

grid.table.on('click', '.link', function(e) {
        showDetails.call(grid, e);
});
```

#### JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qXAf6/7/

Comment: @Brett, thank you so much, you have no idea how much did you help me. I've killed the whole day trying to restore custom buttons after grid.saveAll(). Stupid kendo, "all" part in saveAll should mean "all", not "all but custom buttons and toolbar".